# Disable group selection on ListView Control WinForms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a list view control set to Details view with Groups enabled but when navigating up\down the list with the keyboard the groups are acting as a selectable item, often behaving strangely, selecting the first record on occasion.

**Is there a way to disable the selection of the group items?**

*More info*

Try navigating with the arrow keys, up and down the list - you will notice the group headers are selectable, and behave differently depending on the direction navigated. I want them to be disabled - having the selection jump from the last item in a group to the first item in the next group.

[Download example project](http://www.sendspace.com/file/o0t61t).

I'm populating the control like this:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = CreateData()
Dim itemcoll(3) As String
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
  For j = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
    itemcoll(j) = dt.Rows(i)(j).ToString()
  Next

  Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
  ListView1.Groups.Add(New ListViewGroup(itemcoll(0).Substring(0, 1), itemcoll(0).Substring(0, 1)))
  lvi.Group = ListView1.Groups(itemcoll(0).Substring(0, 1))
  ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

The listview control has the following options changed from standard via the designer:

- AutoArrange: False
- FullRowSelect: True
- HideSelection: False
- MultiSelect: False
- Sorting: Ascending
- View: Details

[image: Example]

You can see above that the Y group header is selected - navigating from Microsoft down selects Yahoo! AND the group header, navigating down again selects Yahoo! only.

Comment: Can you show your ListView creation to see all the properties and so? Ive just tried your code and groups are not selectable.

Answer (score 0):

[Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) and [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) offer this feature out of the box:

```
betterListView.GroupHeaderBehavior = BetterListViewGroupHeaderBehavior.None;
```

You can read more about extended Groups support in our [Documentation](http://www.componentowl.com/documentation/better-listview/data/chapter-groups.html).

Comment: First link can cost up to 8000 dollars per year. Second link is free.